# Is there a function that makes python read only some parts of a string and execute an operation

Tags: python

I'm trying to make my Python read only the first 3 digits of a string and print an answer based on the first three digits of the string.

I tried:

```
if str[1,2,3] = 080:
   print(...)
elif str[123] =090:
   print(,,,)
```

Answer (score 0):

use the index between the subscript like:

```
str[0:3] or str [:3]
```

this will take the cursor from 0th index to 2nd index